# I just got the Lenovo thinkpad Tablet and it won't connect to the internet

Tags: wireless, internet, connection, thinkpad, lenovo

My internet is password protected, and so whenever I enter the password it says "Obtaining IP address" so after doing this for a while it says "Disabled, Secured with WEP" or something like that. Then when I hit connect it does the "Obtaining IP" thing again, then goes back to "Disabled, Secured with WEP". Can anyone tell me what to do? I just got it today from school and it won't connect to my home internet, it's Wi-Fi is turned on and my internet is Wi-Fi, can anyone help?

Comment: Aren't you asked for the password? Do both, hotspot/router and tablet talk WEP? It is a pretty old standard, better to use WPA/WPA2 if available. Use `lspci | grep -i net` to tell us, what hardware you have.

Comment: Are you talking about a tablet of or a tablet as in an iPad? If the latter is true, then this is the wrong stack exchange site.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this is an Android device. The question should be moved to "Android Enthusiasts".

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Tell the tablet to forget the connection and then add a new network connection, give it your routers name, and then the wep or wpa code.

Answer (score 0):

There a problem with the Thinkpad tablet 2; check here
https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-slate-tablets/Thinkpad-Tablet-2-Wifi-Issue/td-p/975029/page/10

http://forum.tabletpcreview.com/lenovo-ibm/56046-thinkpad-tablet-2-wi-fi-reception-issues-solved.html

3 out of 10 of these tablets have this factory error;

contact Lenovo for a replacement.